# How to convert well indented text into one line xml string?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Because it is required, I need to save all my informations in XML file and in only one line.

For example:

```
<tag1 Name="X">
    <tag2 Value="3">
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

would become:

```
<tag1 Name="X"><tag2 Value="3"></tag2></tag1>
```

I just managed to find the reverse of this action from internet. Do you guys have any idea? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're able to use LINQ to XML, and the XML is currently in a file:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("myxmlfile.xml");
document.Save("onelinexml.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

or if you have have XML string:

```
xml.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")
```

Comment: yup, using LINQ with your codes made the thing function, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `"\n"` in the XML string with `""`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this should help you

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("yourxml.xml");
document.Save("file.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```